# Objective-C Passing NSURL to another viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewcontroller, nsurl

I have two view controllers: `FirstViewController` and `SecondViewController`. The project is to record a video and attach it to an email. I can record it and have it able to email, I just need to attach it. I am able to get a URL for the video in `FirstViewController`, but passing it isn't working.

**FirstViewController** -

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info 
{

    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:@"public.movie"])
    {
       // Saving the video to phone / // Get the new unique filename
       NSString *sourcePath = [[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL"]relativePath];

       UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(sourcePath, self, /*@selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)*/nil, nil);
       self.movieURL= [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: sourcePath];
       NSLog(@"movieURL");
       NSLog(self.movieURL.absoluteString);

       SecondViewController *sendMovie = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
       sendMovie.movieU = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: sourcePath];
       [[self navigationController] pushViewController:sendMovie animated:YES];

       NSLog(@"movieU");
       NSLog(sendMovie.movieU.absoluteString);
   }

   [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

**SecondViewController** to attach to email -

```
NSLog(@"1st print");
NSLog(self.movieU);
[controller addAttachmentData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:self.movieU] mimeType:@"video/MOV" fileName:@"defectVideo.MOV"];
NSLog(@"2nd print");
NSLog(self.movieU.absoluteURL);
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

**SecondViewController.h** property of NSURL

```
@property(nonatomic) NSURL *movieU;
```

The `movieURL` is a property in the `FirstViewController`, but I don't believe is needed.

I can see the URL in the `FirstVC`, but it appears nil in the `SecondVC`.

Comment: define NSURL *movieU as a extern instead of property or else define it as a property of AppDelegate and access it!

Comment: it seems like you are attaching first then you are setting movieU for secondVC

Comment: I think the problem is that movieU isn't retained. It might be as simple as changing the property line to `@property(nonatomic, retain) NSURL *movieU`

Comment: When I try to set as an extern, movieU doesn't become recognizable to anything. Adding retain didn't work.

Comment: @AustinMullins properties are declared "strong" by default.  http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#property-declarations

Comment: @SeanCleveland are you using ARC?

Comment: @DylanCrocker Yes, I am using ARC.

Comment: Ok then my comments on the property being retained by default should be valid. Did you try the test in my answer?

Comment: Yes, I tried it. It shows it is isn't nil, but when going to the SecondVC, it says nil. Just weird.

Comment: When is that code in SecondVC called? Is it definitely being called after the URL property is being set? If it's called from the -init method somewhere, it will still be nil.

Comment: @atticus Good point. I actually just put that in my answer. `veiwDidLoad` is also not a good place...

Answer (score 2):

**Solutions** -

1) define `NSURL *movieU` as a `extern` instead of property.

2) else define it as a property of `AppDelegate` and access it.

3) or else `synthesize` property `movieU` and do allocate like -

in your **FirstViewController** -

```
 SecondViewController *sendMovie = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
 NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: sourcePath];
 sendMovie.movieU = url;
 [[self navigationController] pushViewController:sendMovie animated:YES];
```

And `NSLog` it in your **SecondViewController**.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am not sure how to do the extern, if I set it as an extern in the header, every place using it becomes recognizable. I tried to synthesize it with the allocation you wrote, but nothing changed.

Comment: when u define variable as extern, don't synthesize it. But when u define it as property then only synthesize it!

Comment: That was what I was meaning. I only synthesized when as a property. Sorry if I didn't make that clear.

Comment: it's fine. But hope my one of solution worked for u!

Comment: There is no reason to declare the `NSURL` as a variable first (3) - a pointer is a pointer and it will compile just the same.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the way you are going about passing information. Try this:

```
    // In you code where you create the second view controller.
    SecondViewController *sendMovie = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    // SecondViewController viewDidLoad method being called (movieU is still nil)

    sendMovie.movieU = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: sourcePath]; 

    // Do a nil test here
    if (!sendMovie.movieU) {
        NSLog(@"%@",@"It's nil here!"); // If this is the case something is wrong with "sourcePath"
    } else {
        NSLog(@"%@",@"It's not nil here!");
    }

    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:sendMovie animated:YES];
    // SecondViewController viewWillAppear method being called (movieU is NOT nil)
    // SecondViewController viewDidAppear method being called (movieU is NOT nil)
```

This test will tell you a lot. If its nil here then the problem is not with setting the second view controller's property but with actually creating the `NSURL` object. It could be a lot of things like you are overwriting it somewhere in the second view controller (e.g. `viewWillAppear` method). Just follow the trail using break points, logging, etc. to follow its life time.

**Edit - Debugging Procedure**

Set break points where you create Second VC, set its property, push it, and finally view it (clicking on the tab). Set break points throughout the lifecycle of the second VC (`viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear`, `viewDidAppear`, etc). This will allow you to step through the entire lifecycle of your VC. If you haven't utilized those methods go ahead and define them anyway including a call to `super`. As you step through these break points keep checking the value of `movieU`. You will see it is nil at first, then you set it (we know this from your comments), its not nil, then it becomes nil, again, etc. If you are patient and systematic you will find it and learn a whole lot about the lifecycle of VCs. If you don't systematically step through you may miss something. For instance maybe your code is creating a whole new Second VC when you click on the tab to actually look at it. Stepping through your code this way will show that.

**Edit**

Make sure you are testing in the `viewWillAppear`/`viewDidAppear` methods or later so that the property has actually been set. See comments in my code.

**Edit**

> A property of retainable object pointer type which is synthesized without a source of ownership has the ownership of its associated instance variable, if it already exists; otherwise, [beginning Apple 3.1, LLVM 3.1] its ownership is implicitly strong. Prior to this revision, it was ill-formed to synthesize such a property.

From: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#property-declarations

According to this (unless you are specifying weak on the ivar - unlikely) it should be strong by default.

Good luck.

Comment: It looks like the property declaration is fine. I edited my answer to reflect this. Hope its more helpful now.

Comment: Could there be an issue with how I am connecting the viewcontrollers? I am using tabbed view controller set up. Right now, it is set up where once the dismissal of the camera, it pulls back up the FirstViewController, and then you have to select the next tab to the email textfields.

Comment: No the first VC is irrelevant. As long as the `movieU` property of the second VC retains what it gets then that object cannot die until it lets go! Doesn't matter what happens to the first VC. As long as the second one is alive so is the reference count on its properties (unless you manually remove it of course).

Comment: One more question: where are you seeing that the `movieU` property is nil? The second view controller's `viewDidLoad` method perhaps? I've updated the code in my answer to help if this is the case.

Comment: When I go into the SecondVC, movieU becomes nil.

Comment: I'm sorry but what do you mean "When I go into the SecondVC"? What method in the SecondVC are you looking at the property (`init`, `veiwDidLoad`, etc).

Comment: It is the viewDidLoad. I don't have an init method. Whenever I click on the tab for email, movieU shows nil. I know this is a bad suggestion, but can I send you my code? It seems like I have everything right, but there maybe one small thing I am not seeing, and I have tried everyone's suggestions.

Comment: @SeanCleveland Unfortunately I don't have time to do that but I know you can find it by following my advice of carefully following the lifecycle of the Second VC. I'll update my answer to be slightly more helpful for how to go about it.

Comment: I got it fixed! I decided to use a singleton. Thank you for your thorough response! It helped me a lot with helping me debug in the future.

Comment: @SeanCleveland Glad you figured it out! You should post what you did and accept it as the answer for those who stumble across this post in the future with a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
self.movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:sourcePath];
```

instead of

```
self.movieURL= [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: sourcePath];
```

hope this work

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed! I decided to use a singleton which uses a shared instance through another class. I created a whole new class called Singleton and only contained the sharedinstance method:

```
+ (id)sharedInstance {
static id sharedInstance = nil;
if (sharedInstance == nil) {
    sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
}
return sharedInstance;
}
```

Singleton.h

```
 @property NSURL *movieU;
 + (id)sharedInstance;
```

Make sure to import the singleton class to both First and Second VC.

SecondVC.m

```
Singleton* single = [Singleton sharedInstance];
[controller addAttachmentData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: single.movieU] mimeType:@"video/MOV" fileName:@"defectVideo.MOV"];
```

FirstVC.m

```
Singleton* single = [Singleton sharedInstance];

NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
if ([mediaType isEqualToString:@"public.movie"]){
    // Saving the video / // Get the new unique filename
    NSString *sourcePath = [[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL"]relativePath];
    UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(sourcePath, self, /*@selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)*/nil, nil);
    self.movieURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: sourcePath];
    NSLog(@"movieURL");
    single.movieU = self.movieURL;
```

By doing this, it successfully would pass the url containing the information for the recorded video to be attached to the email.